# Retrofit Как узнать завершилось ли выполнение потока (хочу слать запросы не в Activity а в Модели)

Tags: android, многопоточность, запрос, retrofit2

Я хочу слать запросы на получение данных (Retrofit 2 enqueue ) не в Activity, а в модели.

Логика такова.
Из активити я вызываю метод модели для получения некого массива. 
Уже в этом методе идёт запрос retrofit и создаётся массив. Но проблема в том, что я не успеваю вернуть массив активити. Как можно решить эту проблему или всегда нужно жёстко связывать retrofit и активити?

Вот пример кода того, что я хочу:
Activity (часть кода опустил)

```
  CalculatorModel calculatorModel = new CalculatorModel();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, calculatorModel.getBankArray());
```

Модель

```
 private List<BankModel> bankModelList;
  private void getBank() {
    App.getApi().getBank().enqueue(new Callback<List<BankModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<BankModel>> call, 
    Response<List<BankModel>> response) {
            if (response.body() != null) {
                bankModelList = new ArrayList<>();
                bankModelList.addAll(response.body());
               }
           }

            @Override
           public void onFailure(Call<List<BankModel>> call, Throwable t) {
           }
        });
     }

   public String[] getBankArray() {
 getBank();
    int sizeBankArray = bankModelList.size();

    String[] bankArray = new String[sizeBankArray];

    for (int i = 0; i <= sizeBankArray; i++) {
        bankArray[i] = bankModelList.get(i).getNameBank();
    }

    return bankArray;
}
```

Хочу реализовать что-то похожее и отделить все запросы от активити и вынести их в модель/контроллер.
Как мне это реализовать?
Может через Observer ?

Comment: можно использовать синглтон, удобная штука, поможет вынести все запросы и просто брать в активности данные

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете создать класс для работы с моделью, например Presenter в MVP. В нем вы можете создать объект Retrofit и получить свой массив в методе onResponse и через используя интерфейс  передать в активити свой массив для работы с ним.

https://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/473-mvp-na-primere-jekrana-s-pin-kodom.html здесь можно посмотреть как вообще работает паттерн MVP.

P.S. при необходимости позднее могу написать пример с кодом.

P.P.S. Вот пример кода:

Есть модель

RestApi

```
public class RestApi {
    private final static String BASE_URL = <YOUR BASE URL>;
    private static final int TIMEOUT_IN_SECOND = 2;

    private static RestApi sRestApi;
    private static IEndPoint sEndPoint;

    private RestApi() {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = buildOkHttpClient();
        Retrofit sRetrofit = buildRetrofit(okHttpClient);

        sEndPoint = sRetrofit.create(IEndPoint.class);
    }

    public static synchronized RestApi getInstance() {
        if (sRestApi == null) {
            sRestApi = new RestApi();
        }
        return sRestApi;
    }

    public IEndPoint getEndPoint() {
        return sEndPoint;
    }

    private OkHttpClient buildOkHttpClient() {
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_SECOND, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_SECOND, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
    }

    private Retrofit buildRetrofit(OkHttpClient client) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
}
```

IEndPoint

public interface IEndPoint {

```
@GET("phone_masks")
Call<List<BankModel>> getData();
```

}

IPublisher

```
public interface IPublisher {

    Call<List<BankModel>> getData();

}
```

Model

```
public class Model extends BaseModel implements IPublisher {

    @Override
    public Call<List<BankModel>> getData() {
        return RestApi.getInstance().getEndPoint().getData();
    }
}
```

Вот примерно так выглядит модель! Далее есть интерфейс контракт для взаимодействия активити с презентером

```
public interface IActivityContract {

    interface Presenter {

        void loadData();
    }

    interface View extends IView {

        void updateData(List<Post> data);
    }
}
```

Есть класс активити примерно такой

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements IActivityContract.View {

    private PostsListScreenPresenter mPresenter;
    private PostAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView mPostsRecyclerView;
    //some code


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_posts_list);

        init();
        initRecycler();
        mPresenter.attachView(this);
        mPresenter.loadData();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mPresenter.detachView();
    }

    @Override
    public void updateData(List<BankModel> data) {
        if (mAdapter != null) {
            mAdapter.updateData(data);
        }
    }
    //some code
}
```

И собственно презентер

public class ActivityPresenter extends BasePresenter
        implements IActivityContract.Presenter {

```
private Model mModel;

public ActivityPresenter(){
    mModel = new Model();
}

@Override
public void viewIsReady() {

}

@Override
public void loadData() {
    mModel.getData(new Callback<List<BankModel>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<BankModel>> call, 
Response<List<BankModel>> response) {
        if (response.body() != null) {
           updateView(List<BankModel>);
           }
       }

        @Override
       public void onFailure(Call<List<BankModel>> call, Throwable t) {
       }
    });
 }
}

private void updateView(List<BankModel> data) {

    getView().updateData(data);
}
```

}

вот примерно так это должно выглядеть.

Comment: Было бы очень здорово показать пример кода

Comment: Добавил код! Примерно так это должно выглядеть. Но здесь могут быть ошибки.